# Delete all .bak files from folder with CMD

Tags: windows-command-prompt, zip

I want automate the delete files with .bak extension in my backup folder

I have a little CMD who ZIP all my  BD .back and after this i want delete this bak but not ZIP file

I use this but dont work, the bak files are in F:\bckup

```
del /s /q /f "F:\bckup*.bak"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZCe.png)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a backslash in the path.

Try `del /s /q /f "F:\bckup\*.bak"`

Comment: I really can't understand how it's possible to not only make typo (it happens), not notice it (it happens too), not notice it when troubleshooting (even this happens)... but to even *post a question here including the typo and not noticing it again*. Do people ever re-read what they write?

Comment: well it could be that he use native paths, however `forfiles` can be also a choice if you're planning to make a delay on the deletion